# How to get array/list of results of RotationMatrix?

Tags: syntax

For most other functions, passing in a list of arguments will return a list of results. E.g.

```
t = Range[0, 10];
m = N[Sin[t]]
```

returns

```
{0., 0.841471, 0.909297, 0.14112, -0.756802, -0.958924, -0.279415,
0.656987, 0.989358, 0.412118, -0.544021}
```

I would like a list of rotation matrices for each element in t like this

```
matList = RotationMatrix[t]
```

but it returns an error. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `Print[{Attributes[Sin], Attributes[RotationMatrix]} ];(* then you need*) RotationMatrix /@ Range@10`

Comment: RotationMatrix does not have attribute Listable. So map it over the list...

Comment: Indeed `RotationMatrix` is not `Listable`, in part because the function can take a list of two vectors as arguments to compute the rotation matrix that takes vector 1 to vector 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RotationMatrix` is not `Listable`

```
Attributes[RotationMatrix]
(* {Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

So you have to use `Map` (or `Table`) here

```
matList = RotationMatrix /@ t
(* {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{Cos[1], -Sin[1]}, {Sin[1], Cos[1]}}, ...} *)
```

You can define custom listable function like this

```
r[t_] := RotationMatrix[t]
SetAttributes[r, Listable]

r[t]
(* {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{Cos[1], -Sin[1]}, {Sin[1], Cos[1]}}, ... } *)
```

Yet another approach is to calculate the rotation matrix analytically. It contains `Sin` and `Cos` which are `Listable`. You can effectively do it with `Block`

```
Block[{t}, RotationMatrix[t]]
(* {{{1, Cos[1], ...}, {0, -Sin[1], ...}}, {{0, Sin[1], ...}, {1, Cos[1], ...}}} *)
```

Note the another order of dimensions.